# VS2010  "The operation could not be completed. Class not registered" when trying to open command window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nuget

My Visual Studio 2010 (with Service Pack 1) install is corrupted.
This is on Windows 7 x64.

When I try to **open a command window** within VS, I get:

> "The operation could not be completed.
>   Class not registered"

When I try to **open the immediate window**, nothing happens.

Others have seen the exact same issue:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562043/immediate-and-command-windows-not-available-in-vs2010-ide

I am working on a clean Windows 7 (x64) install.

I have run a repair, full uninstall & reinstall, with and without service packs, and I keep getting the same error.  I suspect when the uninstall happens, maybe not 100% of everything is being uninstalled....something must be hanging around (libraries, registry entries, etc) that keeps landing me in a corrupted state.  So, I'm wondering if there is some method of doing a "destructive" install, that doesn't worry about the affect it may have on other applications, that may remove more than a standard uninstall does.

**UPDATE:**
The issue *seems* to be related to running on 64 bit windows and where VS is looking for things in the registry, which may or may not be considered a bug in the VS installer.

**UPDATE #2:**
The missing registry entry was:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\CLSID\{182C9FA0-9233-4E5A-994E-9934B4BB2EA4}]
@="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsManagedObjectAggregator"
"Assembly"="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
"Class"="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsManagedObjectAggregator"
"InprocServer32"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
```

So adding that entry cleared up the problem (although, other things related to Add-Ins failed next so I'd have to reinstall those to confirm whether this entirely fixes the problem.)

Comment: Have you tried running as admin (also turn off UAC to get that out of the picture) to see if permissions on config files might be an issue?  Also try starting VS using `"devenv /ResetSettings"` and/or `"devenv /SafeMode"` to see if they make a difference.

Comment: I have this registry key but still have the problem. Re-applying VS2010 SP1 didn't work. Resetting VS settings didn't work. Interestingly, this is first time I tried installing from the DVD and SP1 from an ISO (didn't have network connection at the time).

Comment: In the end, it took at a full repair install and re-application of VS2010 SP1 for it to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a COM error, it is normally an install problem with a COM server not being properly registered by the installer.  A first order diagnostic is to use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to observe the process (devenv.exe) searching the registry for the registry key.  On your machine that will be a subkey of HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID.  Compare the trace you get with one from a good machine to help find the missing key.

This is otherwise pretty unhealthy of course.  Ask at superuser.com for help with determining what might be wrong with the machine's registry.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what the problem is, thanks!  ....trying to track down a working machine to compare against now.....

Answer (score 0):

The "resolution" in this case was to set the compatibility mode (on the VS shortcut) to Windows XP SP3.  I suspect that this reverts to the standard, 32 bit registry lookups rather than searching under the "Wow6432Node" node that occurs by default when on 64bit windows, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever have DevPath env variable setup by you or reflector? if by chance it got deleted please add again it.
In my case I deleted that env var and start getting that error after i recreating same it start working.

Answer (score 0):

You must install or reinstall (without any errors) last version x86 (32bits) AND 64bits **BOTHS** of follows components:

- Visual C++ Redistributable
- Visual C++ SP1 Redistributable
- Crystal Report for Visual Studio